# Override default security for URL

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

By default web application is completely secured for example using

```
security: 
   basic: 
     enabled: true
```

or by including Spring Cloud OAuth2

I would like to enable particular url to be unsecured for example swagger related stuff

```
/v2/docs
```

What is the simplest way of disabling security on one URL and leaving the rest of them protected.

Would like to share same approach across multiple projects - making it sort of autoconfiguration option - if Swagger classes are included then make certain urls unprotected.

Comment: If you say what is your real spring-security configuration, we could try to tell you how to change it...

Comment: Nothing special just include spring-boot-security-starter and this secures everything or if you include spring cloud-security-starter.

Comment: But only want to change particular URL access and inherit the rest of the security configuration. In other words /v2 should be unprotected the rest of the urls still protected with basic security or OAuth2 - however its configured

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works:

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class SwaggerSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/**", "/swagger-ui.html",    "/webjars/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-resources", "/docs");
    }
}
```